# EmberJS checkbox set value

Tags: ember.js, checkbox

According to the ember documentation, I can do this:

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" checked=isAdmin}}
```

This works fine, however... my checkbox, although 'on or off' but consider the following:

```
[ ] Apples
[ ] Blueberries
[ ] Oranges
```

Let's say the 'value' for each one of those is the label... so if someone were to check all 3, it would pass this as an array:

```
["Apples","Blueberries","Oranges"]
```

However, this isn't what happens...I get:

```
["true","true","true"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want checkbox values to be in array form then you have to create `computed property` which will depend on checkbox properties.

```
selectedFruits: Ember.computed('isBananas', 'isBlueberries', 'isOranges', function() {
  var values = [];
  var isBanana = this.get('isBanana');
  var isOranges = this.get('isOranges');
  var isBlueberries = this.get('isBlueberries');
  if (isBanana) { values.push('bananas'); }
  if (isBlueberries) { values.push('blueberries'); }
  if (isOranges) { values.push('oranges'); }
  return values;
});
```

or use ember addon [ember-multiselect-checkboxes](https://github.com/rsschermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes) instead

```
{{multiselect-checkboxes options=fruits selection=selectedFruits}}
```

where `selectedFruits === ['bananas','oranges']` selected items in array

Comment: This is great, I was hoping I could do this:  value="Blueberries", but getting the value still returns 'on'... seems the computed property is the way to go. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Matt will be useful if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493336/ember-loop-through-an-array-of-checkboxes-and-get-checked-items/34493426#34493426

Comment: Ember.Checkbox.reopen({
 attributeBindings: ['value']
});   

will let you specify: value="blueberries" rather than it returning simply 'on' as the default