# Ember loop through an array of checkboxes and get checked items?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js application (using the Ember CLI). I have a component called `sideMenu` with the files `sideMenu.js` and `sideMenu.hbs`. Within the .js file, I have an array of vehicle names like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    vehicles: ['Audi', 'Chrysler', 'Harley Davidson'],
    vehicleCheckboxes: { 'Audi': true, 'Chrysler': true, 'Harley Davidson': true }
});
```

In my template for this component, I am looping through these vehicles and creating a checkbox for each item like this:

```
{{#each vehicles as |vehicle|}}
    {{input type='checkbox' checked='true'}} {{vehicle}}
{{/each}}
```

This gives me what I want - a few checkboxes with the vehicle names next to it. I want to be able to know what the user unchecked / checked in this list. I tried to do this by creating some Ember properties dynamically and in the template:

```
{{input type='checkbox' checked="{{vehicleCheckboxes}}.{{vehicle}}"}}
```

This didn't seem to work though. How can I accomplish this? There doesn't seem to be any indication on the Ember documentation that it is possible from within the framework in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checked` expects boolean value (`true/false`)
you can either use this [addon](https://github.com/rsschermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes) like :

`{{multiselect-checkboxes options=vehicles selection=selectedVehicles}}`

or you can have your loop like this:

```
{{#each vehicles as |vehicle|}}
    {{input type='checkbox' checked=(get vehicleCheckboxes vehicle)}} {{vehicle}}
{{/each}}
```

and you need your `vehicleCheckboxes` converted to Ember.Object I think if it does not work as it is

`vehicleCheckboxes: Ember.Object.create({ 'Audi': true, 'Chrysler': true, 'Harley Davidson': true })`

Comment: The addon you mentioned is perfect! However, I setup an observer on the selection and it doesn't seem to be updating when I interact with the checkboxes. I created a new property in my .js file called `selectedVehicles` and assigned an empty array to it. Should I be doing it any other way?

Comment: I think your array should be `Ember.A()` not `[]`, then you can observe it like `Ember.computed("selectedVehicles.[]",....`

Comment: I declared the array like you mentioned but I'm not sure I understand the observer format you specified. When I type that into my observer, it throws an error. Can you please explain what you meant?

Comment: Ok I got it, I'm observing it as `.observes('selectedVehicles.@each')` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: sorry yeah you should in most cases avoid observers, so what I typed there is actually different form of creating computed property, anyways if you need it observer you do `Ember.observer('selectedVehicles.[]')` or `function(){}.observes('selectedVehicles.[]')`

Comment: This solutions works well for browser behavior.  But it fails when doing unit tests for me.
Upon doing this test code: `this.$('#body-part-head').click()`, then I receive: `Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed 32` in the test failure.